# Sign only a specific commit from history

Tags: git

Is there a way to sign only a specific commit from history?
This `git rebase --exec 'git commit --amend --no-edit -n -S' -i commit_id`
Would promt me to rebase all the commits starting with the given commit Id, I'd like to sign just a specific commit that I forgot to sign

Comment: It's impossible to modify a commit. Once created, you get the ID, end of story. Adding a signature would create a _new_ commit with a different ID.

Comment: Problem is when I rebase, and want to exec only the sign command, it promts me with lots of conflicts and I do have 200~ ish commits...

Comment: If you have a complex tree to rebase (say, it has merges), you will be falling into a rebase corner-case. By default, it does _not_ rebase merges... os if you had to correct conflicts in merges, you lose that code.... and so conflicts are expected when commits try to apply changes on those changes that are lost because of the missing merges... _and_, if you decide to use `--rebase-merges`, I think git does _not_ currently try to use the conflict resolution used in the merge that is being applied (if there were conflicts in the original commit), so you end up with conflicts in that case.....

Comment: What you _can_ do, if you are sure that you are not introducing a change in the code tree and you would expect then to have commits that resemble exactly the original commits is use `--rebase-merges` and every time that a merge fails because there are conflicts is blindly tell git to just get the contents from the original commit... which would be possible to do by using `git restore --staged --worktree --source=REBASE_HEAD -- .` which is just telling git: _just get the contents from the original commit_ and then `git rebase --continue`. Keep _an  eye_ on the results cause I haven't tried it

Comment: As @eftshift0 has pointed out, it would cause a mess to rewrite a commit which is very far away from the head. A workaround is to create a signed annotated tag on that commit.

Comment: _and_ not to mention that all the signed commits that are following would also need to get new signatures.

Comment: 200 ish commits looks like an impossible job to handle with a `git rebase`. Are there signed commits in those 200 ish commits ?

Comment: Yes, I have basically 8~ commits scattered across the 200 that are not signed

Comment: Note that you can make an annotated, signed *tag* that verifies that you approve of the commit. This is not the same thing (and uses SHA1, which is a bit weak in terms of security). But signing a later commit *implicitly* signs all the commits leading up to that commit, the same way a tag does, so there's no real point here.